# How to make sure that association exists and load it to avoid N+1 in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following associations:

```
A User has_many House
A House belongs_to User
```

I know that if I want to find all the unique users that has at least a house, I would do this:

```
User.joins(:houses).uniq
```

Now, how would I proceed if once I found those users, I want to act on their houses. How would I load the houses on memory, so that I could act on them, such as:

```
User.joins(:houses).uniq.each do |user|
  user.houses.each { |h| do_something_with_house(h) }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `User.includes(:houses).joins(:houses).uniq`?

You should see a second select, pulling all houses. So whenever you do user.houses they are in memory for you.

Read more at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations